как писать в лог с нужной частотой
есть скрипт
sh script.sh > log
как сделать что бы в лог писались данные раз в 5 минут и script.sh продолжал работать, script.sh сканирует компьютер на некоторые действия
или в случае если script.sh прервется по любой причине, что бы в лог была гарантированая запись

cron

Если просто надо вызывать script.sh каждые 5 минут и выводить его stdout в log-file, то например bash -c '( while [ true ]; do script.sh; sleep 300; done ) >log'  (sleep 300 это пауза в 5 минут)

Чтобы вывод дописывался в конец файла, испльзовать оператор перенаправления ">>"
